# Casting dynamically allocated arrays of arbitrary pointers in ANSI C

Tags: c, linux

This fairly straightforward snippet constructed out of a much larger body of code that gives the "warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]".

For simplicity I have even changed the caddr_t's to char *... in reality this is part of a set of routines that dynamically generate structures and in this case creates an array which may contain arbitrary pointers to arbitrary malloc'd structures. And left out the struct that the calloc'd array gets inserted into.

It's the way I did OO back in the 80's and I have a lot of code that works this way.

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int n = 10;
  int i;
  char *p;

  p = (char *) calloc(n,sizeof(char *));
  for (i=0; i<n; i++) {p[i] = (char *) NULL;}
}
```

So is there an easy way to make a modern C happy or do I have to use a -W switch to tell it to just go away and not bother me?

And yes, I prefer a C that acts like a set of macro's for PDP-11 assembler ;-)

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention... n is calculated at run time, so it is not available at compile time.

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program. You don't need to cast `NULL` either.

Answer (score 5):

you should be declaring `p` as `char ** p`, if you want an array of pointers.

Then either remove the cast before calloc or cast it with ( char ** )

Comment: Thanks. I was playing around with cdecl and things like char *(*var)[] and getting nowhere. Also helped me clear up some other lint.

Answer (score 4):

You're getting the warning because this statement:

```
p[i] = (char *)NULL;
```

Is assigning a pointer to an integer - `p[i]` is a `char`.  To get this program to behave correctly, you'll want to change `p` to be `char **`, rather than `char *`.  That is - it should be an array of pointers to strings, not a pointer to an array of characters.

In addition, you can get rid of those typecasts and the parentheses in the `sizeof` operator.

```
char **p = calloc(n, sizeof *p);
```

And

```
p[i] = NULL;
```

Are a lot easier to read.

Even better, since the null pointer constant is almost certainly an all-zero bit pattern on your machine, you don't need the loop doing the assignment at all - the `calloc` call already zeroed out the memory for you.

Here's a simplified program that's semantically identical to yours, assuming that's the case:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  int n = 10;
  char **p = calloc(n, sizeof *p);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I started off without most of the casts and just kept adding more trying to bend C to my will :-)

Answer (score 1):

The reason the compiler is upset is that you have:

```
char *p;
```

and then you are assigning pointers `(char *)NULL` to characters `char` at:

```
p[i] = (char *)NULL;
```

You should probably be using:

```
char **p = (char **)calloc(n, sizeof(char *));
```

but if you use `calloc()`, the subsequent loop is superfluous anyway (unless you're on a weird machine where the in-memory representation of a null pointer is not all bits zero, but then you should probably not use `calloc()` but simply use `malloc()` anyway).

There are those who excoriate the use of casts on `malloc()` and `calloc()`; I'm not in that school, having worked on systems (pre-standard C) where the cast was necessary. I compile with options that ensure that my code doesn't run foul of the problems that those who excoriate casts are afraid of.

Comment: Yep. And I have run across some folks who don't like caddr_t either... I find it a very useful way to do OO like things. void * seems to sometimes give you headaches but caddr_t/char * almost never does.